# Múltiples marcadores para un mapa de Google Maps v3

Tags: php, javascript, google-maps

Estoy desarrollando un mapa en el cual muestro marcadores de distintos "colores" o 
"formas". Por lo menos es la intención. Al mismo tiempo quiero que el usuario si toca un marcador, se le muestre información que viene de la Base de datos.
Por eso, cuando accedo a la página creo un json con toda la información que necesito:

```
<?php
  session_start();
  require '../../includes/conexion.php';
  include '../../includes/funcs_pdo.php';

  $conexion = new Conexion();
  $stmt = $conexion -> prepare("SELECT id, user, tipo, lat, lng, descripcion, instalo, idtipo FROM markers WHERE visible=1 ORDER BY id DESC");
  $stmt->execute();
  $userData = array();

  while($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    $userData['Marcadores'][] = $row;
  }
  $jsonMarkers = json_encode($userData);
?>
```

Ahora bien, toda la documentación que encontré sobre marcadores múltiples muestran 3 o 4 marcadores estáticos, pero ningún ejemplo tratan de cómo manejar los datos, o recorrer los datos de un json.
Encontré la forma de testear multiples marcadores aleatorios con lo siguiente:

```
 <script>
 (...)

   for (var i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(southWest.lat() + latSpan * Math.random(), southWest.lng() + lngSpan * Math.random()),
            map: map,
            title: 'Prueba ' + i
        });

        // info windows
        (function(marker, i) {
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                    content: 'Prueba'
                });
                infowindow.open(map, marker);
            });
        })(marker, i);
    }
  </script>
```

me faltaría cómo asignar cada latitud y longitud del json a este código y además cómo analizo el campo "idtipo" que define si el marcador es de un color u otro color. Por otra parte, los otros campos del json son para "armar" el infowindow del marcador en cuestión...
Alguien puede darme una mano ?
Desde ya muchas gracias

---

un ejemplo del json que levanto cuando entro a la pagina es: (esto es lo que obtengo cuando hago echo $jsonMarkers;

```
{"Marcadores":[
  {"id":17,"user":1,"tipo":"TIPO 1","lat":"-36.05254","lng":"-67.98","descripcion":"PRUEBA DESDE NETBEANS","instalo":"HABRIA QUE VER","idtipo":1},
  {"id":16,"user":1,"tipo":"TIPO 3","lat":"-34.66648","lng":"-58.48512","descripcion":null,"instalo":"","idtipo":4},
  {"id":15,"user":1,"tipo":"TIPO 1","lat":"-34.66741","lng":"-58.48606","descripcion":null,"instalo":"","idtipo":1},
  {"id":14,"user":1,"tipo":"TIPO 2","lat":"-34.66701","lng":"-58.48604","descripcion":null,"instalo":"","idtipo":2},
  {"id":13,"user":1,"tipo":"TIPO 3","lat":"-34.66662","lng":"-58.48559","descripcion":null,"instalo":"","idtipo":4},
  {"id":12,"user":1,"tipo":"TIPO 3","lat":"-29.49699","lng":"-64.42383","descripcion":null,"instalo":"","idtipo":4},
  {"id":11,"user":2,"tipo":"TIPO 4","lat":"-38.25544","lng":"-58.13965","descripcion":"prueba otra mas","instalo":"direccion","idtipo":3},
  {"id":10,"user":2,"tipo":"TIPO 2","lat":"-37.90953","lng":"-58.3374","descripcion":"prueba otra mas","instalo":"direccion","idtipo":2},
  {"id":9,"user":2,"tipo":"TIPO 1","lat":"-29.15216","lng":"-60.86426","descripcion":"prueba otra mas","instalo":"direccion","idtipo":1},
  {"id":8,"user":2,"tipo":"TIPO 4","lat":"-24.04646","lng":"-66.44531","descripcion":"prueba otra mas","instalo":"direccion","idtipo":3},
  {"id":7,"user":1,"tipo":"TIPO 4","lat":"-36.03133","lng":"-63.80859","descripcion":"otra prueba mas","instalo":"","idtipo":3},
  {"id":6,"user":2,"tipo":"TIPO 1","lat":"-27.9265","lng":"-58.3594","descripcion":null,"instalo":"A VERIFICAR","idtipo":1},
  {"id":5,"user":5,"tipo":"TIPO 1","lat":"-34.6468","lng":"-68.2471","descripcion":null,"instalo":"","idtipo":1},
  {"id":4,"user":5,"tipo":"TIPO 2","lat":"-31.2034","lng":"-67.9834","descripcion":null,"instalo":"A VERIFICAR","idtipo":2},
  {"id":3,"user":2,"tipo":"TIPO 2","lat":"-32.5283","lng":"-61.4246","descripcion":null,"instalo":"VALOR A INGRESAR","idtipo":2},
  {"id":2,"user":2,"tipo":"TIPO 1","lat":"-35.626","lng":"-58.1506","descripcion":null,"instalo":"","idtipo":1},
  {"id":1,"user":2,"tipo":"TIPO 1","lat":"-35.03","lng":"-59.5898","descripcion":null,"instalo":"A CONFIRMAR","idtipo":1}
]}
```

Comment: si entendí bien, tu problema es `recorrer los datos de un json` , no un problema de google maps. Te recomiendo [edit] tu pregunta con el json que deseas usar en el mapa y, si es posible, usa el code snippet para crear un [ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Saludos.

Comment: El problema es con google maps, ya que tengo que colocar diferentes tipos de marcadores pero si no puedo recorrer el json, no puedo resolver el problema del mapa...

Comment: pon un ejemplo del JSON

Comment: ¿y además, como pasas el json de php a js?

Comment: var data = <?php echo $jsonMarkers; ?>;

Comment: @MNibor ¿Dónde haces eso? ¿Y qué errores ves en la consola de JS?

Comment: Abro el archivo con el bloque php donde armo el $jsonMarkers. Despues en el head tengo todo el script de carga del mapa. Dentro de ese script, tengo ese pasaje, mas abajo puse un alert(data.lenght) para ver cuántos registros trae y en la consola me dice el error: at Array.<anonymous> Y por pantalla me sale un mensaje del tipo alert que dice "undefined"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ojo!, el problema es tuyo y no de google maps.

Sabemos que para crear multiples marcadores que vienen desde tu json, primero debes RECORRER el json.

```
$.each(tuJSON, function(marcador, index) {

});
```

Sabemos tambien como declarar un marcador que es mas o menos asi:

```
marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(latitud, longitud),
    map: map
});
```

Pero tambien, tenemos la opcion `icon` que nos permite cambiar el icono, color etc, por ejemplo:

```
icon: 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/green-dot.png'
```

Juntando todo esto:

```
$.each(tuJSON, function(marcador, index) {
    var icon = 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/green-dot.png';
    if (marcador.idtipo === 2) {
        icon = 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/red-dot.png'
    }      
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(marcador.latitud, marcador.longitud),
        icon: icon,
        map: map
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: marcador.mensaje
        });
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
    });
});
```

Luego agregar tu marcador al mapa.

Comment: EL json lo paso como  
var data = <?php echo $jsonMarkers; ?>; pero no funciona... en php si tengo el json cargado en esa variable, pero no lo toma en js

Comment: @MNibor eso no funcionara, lo que debes hacer es consumir un servicio o un archivo, a través de ajax y asi obtenerlo en el javascript

Comment: dices que tengo que crear un archivo json y levantarlo desde javascript ?

Comment: Recuerda que javascript es un lenguaje del lado cliente y php del lado servidor, por eso debes acceder a el mediante una petición ajax